# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular

I am new in rest APIs. this rest API for user login but it does not work perfectly 
[image]
[image]

```
  loginUser(value) {
     this.http.get(`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/custom-plugin/login? 
       username=${value.username}&password=${value.password}`)
      .subscribe(data => {
      localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(value));
       console.log('this is value of', value);
       this.jsonapi = data
       localStorage.setItem('ID', JSON.stringify(this.jsonapi.ID));
       localStorage.setItem('user_email',this.jsonapi.data.user_email);
       console.log("loginSuccess", this.jsonapi)
      this.router.navigate(['home'], { state: value }) 
    },

error => {
  console.
  error(" Error ", error)
})
```

}

Comment: Can you post the JSON payload?

Comment: @Sid yes I upload image

Comment: Can you validate the JSON in a linter?

Comment: @Sid yes I already check-in

Comment: It might be going wrong in your interceptor.. maybe log the response there first an see what it looks like?

Comment: Show the network response from the chrome debugger

Comment: @MikeOne  yes you are right this issue is an interceptor issue. if I commit interceptor code than it's working fine